# Definition for different arrhythmia

Tags: cardiology, electrophysiology, heart-failure

I am wondering if there is an organization, a document or a research that standardize all the rhythms? Such as describing how long should the ECG be flatline to be considered as asystole? The rhythm I am focusing on is:

1. Asystole
2. Missed beat
3. Tachycardia
4. Bradycardia
5. PAC
6. PVC
7. Bigeminy
8. Trigeminy
9. Atrial Fibrillation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Basic Cardiac Rhythms – Identification and Response (The University of Toledo, Medical Center)](https://utmc.utoledo.edu/depts/nursing/pdfs/Basic%20EKG%20Refresher.pdf)

This quite thorough one-page source describes:

- Basic heart anatomy and physiology
- The meaning of the waves in ECG
- Examples of ECGs for most arrhythmias with timing, causes, symptoms and treatment

Here's [Pocket Guide to *Neonatal* ECG Interpretation (NICU INK Book Publishers)](http://www.academyofneonatalnursing.org/NNT/Cardiac_ECG.pdf) - an one-page source about arrhythmias in infants.